# How to show alert if variable repeats?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to show an alert if you try to set the variable to the same value?

Example:

```
<h1 id="t_example" onclick="examplefunction()"></h1>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var example = "example"
function examplefunction(){
    example = "example2"
}
```

And now if the user clicks again I want to show the alert saying that the user can't click it again, because it has the same value.

```
 if  (example == "example2"){
     alert() // You have inserted the same value
 }
```

Comment: [almartinez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7772607/almartinez) What do u mean by variable repeats??

Comment: @JinsPeter already solved

Comment: I just want to know you exact requirment..

Comment: @JinsPeter it's already solved but just check if the value of the variable is one and if it repeats shows the alert, see the answer and you will see it better

Comment: In my answer I just wrote the example function defenition. And it is exactly the same logic  you accepted as answer

Comment: @JinsPeter it is similar but don't work the way i want, already tested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this: First check if is same or not. If it is the same alert, the text is not replacing the variable.

```js
var example = "example"

function examplefunction() {
    if  (example == "example2"){
        alert('same value')
    }
    else {
        example = "example2"
    }
    console.log(example)
}
console.log(example)
```

```html
<h1 id="t_example" onclick="examplefunction()">check</h1>
```

Comment: So it will only show the alert on the onclick right? because if i want to put more than one onclick to change the variable to diferents values it will show the alert

Comment: then thanks if it works that way it's the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function examplefunction(){
     if(example !=="example2" ){
        example = "example2"
     }
     else{
       alert("Please dont click again")
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking multiple items clicks:

```js
var clickArr = [];
function examplefunction(value){
    if (clickArr.indexOf(value) != -1) { // If already clicked
        alert("Already clicked");
    } else { // Save in the array if clicked for the first time
        clickArr.push(value);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="t_example1" onclick="examplefunction('example1')">click1</h1>
<h1 id="t_example2" onclick="examplefunction('example2')">click2</h1>
```

Comment: why do u put the `-1` i mean, what's the utility of that, just want to know

Comment: indexOf is to check the value's index in array - starts from 0 . if not present it will return -1